# Function to multiply a number (x) by a given number (y) a certain number of times (n)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function that will multiply a number (x) by a given number (y) a certain number of times (n). The results are to be returned in an array.

```
function multiplyBy(x, y, n) {
    var arr = [],
        z = x * y,
        sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += z;
        arr.push(sum);
    }
    return arr;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/marcusdei/s91pm82b/4/

Comment: Where are you using `n`?

Comment: Could you give an example of the output you're looking for? Could you explain why you are using an array, but no loops or recursion?

Comment: And what do you mean "a number of times".  Are you talking about x * y to the power of n?

Comment: Check this latest version: http://jsfiddle.net/marcusdei/s91pm82b/4/
I need to get [8,32,128,512,2048,8192] instead of [8,16,24,32,40,48].

Comment: Please edit your original question, to clearly show example input and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
function multiplyBy(x, y, n) {
    var arr = [];
    var tot = x*y;
    for (var i=0; i<n; i++){
        arr.push(tot);
        tot *= y;
    }
    return arr;
};

alert(multiplyBy(2,4,6))
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what it means but OP specs demand that "*the results are to be returned in an array*".

Comment: I need to get [8,32,128,512,2048,8192] instead of [8,16,24,32,40,48].

Comment: Is that what you wanted?

Comment: That's exactly it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like [this updated](http://jsfiddle.net/s91pm82b/5/) fiddle?

UPDATE 2:

```
function multiplyBy(x, y, n) {
    var arr = [],
        z = x * y,
        sum = 0;

    arr[0] = x * y;

    for (var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        sum = arr[i - 1] * y;
        arr.push(sum);
    }
    return arr;
};
```

Comment: Close, check out: http://jsfiddle.net/marcusdei/s91pm82b/4/

Instead of [8,16,24,32,40,48] I need to get [8,16,24,32,40,48]

Comment: Aren't those the same? [8,16,24,32,40,48] and [8,16,24,32,40,48]?

Comment: Sorry I mean i need to get [8,32,128,512,2048,8192]

Comment: It should be like 8,64,512,4096,32768,262144

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned `multiplyBy(2, 4, 6);` and desired out put is `8,32,128,512,2048,8192`

```js
function multiplyBy(x, y, n) {
    var arr = [],
    var z = x * y;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr.push(z);
        z *= y;
    }
    return arr;
};
document.getElementById('choice').innerHTML = multiplyBy(2, 4, 6);
```

```css
#hidden {
    display:none
}
```

```html
<div id="choice"></div>
<div id="hidden"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more parsimonious function.

JS:

```
function multiply(op1, op2, n) {
    for(var results = []; n > 0; results.push(op1 *= op2), n--);
    return results;
}

console.log(multiply(2, 4, 6));
```